# OpenCV - segfault instantiating surf feature detector

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I am using the C++ implementation of OpenCV 2.4.6.1 for Ubuntu 12.10 on a x86_64 architecture. I have been experimenting with some of the feature detectors. Recently I found an issue while instantiating SURF detector through the FeatureDetector::create method.

I am able to instantiate and use free detectors such as FAST or BRISK by doing:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("FAST");
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("BRISK");
```

but I am obtaining a segmentation fault at the early moment that I instantiate and try to use non free detectors like SURF or SIFT by doing:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
```

Nonetheless I can instantiate them using directly the concrete class that implements them:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = new cv::SurfFeatureDetector();
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = new cv::SiftFeatureDetector();
```

I am requiring to hot switch the detector/descriptor on runtime and though I could tweak my system to instantiate SURF and SIFT detectors when chosen I consider the right way of proceeding is through the Factory Class that provide instances.

I cannot figure out why is this occurring, in several examples on the Web using the FeatureDetector factory for this type detectors is totally legal. I tried adding the headers for the nonfree module but got the same result.

I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: Did you remember to call  cv::initModule_nonfree(); in main, before doing anything else?

Comment: Thanks, know it works though I am confused because the [SURF documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#surf-operator) states it is necessary if I am using the C version while I always thought I was using the C++ version because I'm including the .hpp headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call cv::initModule_nonfree(); in main, before doing anything else.

Comment: `error C2039: 'initModule_nonfree': is not a member of  'cv'`, need to  `#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>` first